# Extract values from a tab-delimited file column and calculate

Tags: python

I have a variable containing values in multiple lines. I extracted these values from a position/column in a tab-delimited file with multiple lines. The delimited file looks like this.

```
var = ['John', '1', '100']
      ['Peter', '2', '200']
      ['Allen', '3', '300']
```

After extracting the values from position 2, I got these values with the corresponding data type.

```
100
200
300
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

How can I convert the extracted values to a single line as an integer so I can calculate the values like this:

```
var = 100, 200, 300
sum(var)
600
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] along with some actual sample data — what you say the variable contains isn't valid and doesn't make much sense. We also shouldn't need to guess how you're extracting values from position 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an assumption about how *var* is really defined which leads to:

```
var = [['John', '1', '100'],
      ['Peter', '2', '200'],
      ['Allen', '3', '300']]

print(sum(map(int, (v[2] for v in var))))
```

**Output:**

```
600
```

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the values in position 2 to a new array and pass that into sum:

```
readValues = [['John', '1', '100'],
      ['Peter', '2', '200'],
      ['Allen', '3', '300'],
      ['Oops no value', '4']]

# do it all on one line, which is kind of hard to read.
# checks that the readValue is at least length 2 to have a value, otherwise assigns zero.
secondPositionValues = [int(readValue[2]) for readValue in readValues if len(readValue)>=3 else 0]

summed = sum(secondPositionValues)

print(summed)
```

For better readability, do the same thing on multiple lines:

```
readValues = [['John', '1', '100'],
      ['Peter', '2', '200'],
      ['Allen', '3', '300'],
      ['Oops no value', '4']]


secondPositionValues = []
for readValue in readValues:
    if len(readValue)>=3:
        secondPositionValues.append(int(readValue[2]))

summed = sum(secondPositionValues)

print(summed)
```